# Solving ODE with Neumann boundary conditions

Tags: systems-of-equations, boundary-value-problem

How can I solve the ODE with boundary conditions? I have solved it without boundary conditions. I have no idea with such boundary conditions.

ODE:

$${\partial ^2 Y(X) \over \partial ^2 X} = \beta Y(X)$$

Boundary Conditions：

$${\partial \ln Y(X) \over \partial X}
= \begin{cases}
   a  < 0,X = k \\[5pt] 
   b ,    X = 0 \\[5pt]
   c  > 0,X =  - k
\end{cases} 
$$

where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ are given and $X$, $Y$ and $\beta$ are unkown.

Comment: Is $\beta$ an unknown? Is it, perhaps, something that has to be determined upon imposing the condition at $x = 0$? And more importantly, what have you tried?

Comment: Note that if $a,b,c$ and $\beta$ are given constants, your problem is then overdetermined. How could you impose a third boundary condition when the problem is second-order?

Comment: Why has this been given two votes up? The OP showed no effort what so ever.

Comment: $\beta$ is an unknown. Because I don't how to solve ODE with such boundary condition, I treat it as temporary "know" to simplify the problem.  There is no restriction on b where $X = 0$.  @Dmoreno

Comment: I don't know if I'm getting this right. The constant $\beta$ is an unknown, which makes sure that all 3 boundary conditions are satisfied, that is, it's an 'eigenvalue' of the problem. But you say that $a,b$ and $c$ are real and fixed (given), right? Where are you having troubles specifically? Solve the ODE as usual, impose the boundary conditions at $X = \pm k$ and write down what you would get for the third one. Maybe that gives you a condition for $\beta$...